# Compute possible outcomes when get balls from a box

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a question about probability that need your help. I have three boxes: first box has $k_1$ red balls, second box has $k_2$ blue balls and third box has $p_1$ red balls and $p_2$ blue balls. I will throw these balls of two boxes in the third box. Let $n_1=k_1+p_1$ be red balls, $n_2=k_2+p_2$ be blue balls. The total balls in third box is $n=n_1+n_2$

Let $A$ be event that  get $r,(r=r_1+r_2)$, balls from third box (where $r_1,r_2$ are number of red,blue balls, respectively).

How to compute the possible outcomes that $r_1\ge k_1$, $r_2\ge k_2$ from given $r$ balls. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, you have a population of $n$ balls, of which $n_1$ are red, from which you extract a sample (drawn without repetition) of size $r$, which will contain a random variable, $r_1$, of red balls and wish to evaluate $\mathsf P(k_1\leq r_1\leq \min\{n_1,r\}, k_2\leq r-r_1\leq \min\{n-n_1, r\})$.

The count of red balls within the sample, $r_1$ is a random variable with a hypergeometric distribution.

$$\mathsf P(r_1=x) = \frac{\binom{n_1}{x}\binom{n-n_1}{r-x}}{\binom{n}{r}} \quad : x\in\{0...n_1\}$$

Use this to evaluate the desired probability.

$$\begin{align}
 & \quad \mathsf P(k_1\leq r_1\leq \min\{n_1,r\}, k_2\leq r-r_1\leq \min\{n-n_1,r\})
\\ & = \mathsf P(\max\{k_1,r-n+n_1\}\leq r_1\leq \min\{n_1,r-k_2\}) 
\\ & = \sum_{x=\max\{k_1,r-n+n_1\}}^{\min\{n,r-k_2\}} \frac{\binom{n_1}{x}\binom{n-n_1}{r-x}}{\binom{n}{r}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think you are very expert in that are. I am confusing the range of $min\{ n,r-k_2\}$. As the reference https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5d8rrpet49kqhi/2012_BL_EL_Raptor.pdf?dl=0 in eq. (3), the range look like $min\{ n_1,r\}$

Comment: Could you explain the why we have $min$ and $max$ range? Do you think which $min \{ n1,r-k_2\}$ or $min \{ n1,r\}$ is correct?

Comment: The range comes from rearranging and combining the two criteria for $r_1\geq k_1, r_2\geg k_2$

Comment: I am very thankful to you about your help. It is very good explanation. Now, I just am confusing about range $min\{n_1,r−k_2\}$ or $min\{n1,r\}$. The formula in my reference almost same your equation, but only mirror difference is $min\{n1,r\}$.